# WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, csrf

I am sending data from view to controller with AJAXand I got this error:

> WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

I think I have to send this token with data.

Does anyone know how can I do this ?

**Edit: My solution**

I did this by putting the following code inside the AJAX post:

```
headers: {
  'X-Transaction': 'POST Example',
  'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
},
```

Comment: do you have **<%= csrf_meta_tag %>** in your layout header?

Comment: yes like this : <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

Comment: do you have **jquery-rails** libraries that provide ajax client-side functionality?

Comment: And the HAML way is to add "= csrf_meta_tags"

Comment: What does the 'X-Transaction' line do? Seems to work fine without it.

Comment: May I ask you if you can answer this very similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159847/single-page-application-and-csrf-token

Answer (score 409, accepted):

You should do this:

1. Make sure that you have `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` in your layout
2. Add `beforeSend` to all the ajax request to set the header like below:

---

```
$.ajax({ url: 'YOUR URL HERE',
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
  data: 'someData=' + someData,
  success: function(response) {
    $('#someDiv').html(response);
  }
});
```

To send token in all requests you can use:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  }
});
```

Comment: The jQuery UJS library provided by the Rails team adds the CSRF token to jQuery AJAX request automatically. The README contains instructions on how to get setup. https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L91

Comment: Note that you can set the header for all requests at once with the $.ajaxSetup function.

Comment: Excellent! Been searching for a while for this answer. Works seamlessly. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesConroy-Finn This stopped working in Rails 4. Still trying to figure out why.

Comment: Unfortunatly, this solution doesn't work in Rails 4.2.x.

Comment: As a note, if you are using jQuery UJS as suggested above, you need to ensure that the rails-ujs include comes *after* the jquery include or it will fail with the same error as the op.

Comment: May I ask you if you can answer this very similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159847/single-page-application-and-csrf-token

Answer (score 31):

The best way to do this is actually just use `<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>` to print out the token directly in your rails code. You dont need to use javascript to search the dom for the csrf token as other posts mention. just add the headers option as below;

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  data: $(this).sortable('serialize'),
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': '<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>'
  },
  complete: function(request){},
  url: "<%= sort_widget_images_path(@widget) %>"
})
```

Comment: Instead of doing this for each ajax command, you could add **headers** to [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/).

Comment: I'd rather recommend using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8798687/164989)...

Comment: I don't really like the approach of using ERB in the javascript.

Comment: This forces you to generate your javascript with ERB, which is very limiting. Even if there are places where ERB might be a good fit, there are others where it's not, and adding it just to get the token would be a waste.

Answer (score 22):

If I remember correctly, you have to add the following code to your form, to get rid of this problem:

```
<%= token_tag(nil) %>
```

Don't forget the parameter.

Comment: Actually, this should be: `<%= token_tag(nil) %>`. Then you get the auto-generated token.

Answer (score 15):

Indeed simplest way. Don't bother with changing the headers.

Make sure you have:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %> in your layouts/application.html.erb
```

Just do a hidden input field like so:

```
<input name="authenticity_token" 
               type="hidden" 
               value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>"/>
```

Or if you want a jQuery ajax post:

```
$.ajax({     
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<%= someregistration_path %>",
    data: { "firstname": "text_data_1", "last_name": "text_data2", "authenticity_token": "<%= form_authenticity_token %>" },                                                                                  
    error: function( xhr ){ 
      alert("ERROR ON SUBMIT");
    },
    success: function( data ){ 
      //data response can contain what we want here...
      console.log("SUCCESS, data="+data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Adding the hidden input field to my input form solved the problem for me.

Comment: this is done automatically if you use Rails' form helpers.

Answer (score 13):

Ugrading from an older app to rails 3.1, including the csrf meta tag is still not solving it.  On the rubyonrails.org blog, they give some upgrade tips, and specifically this line of jquery which should go in the head section of your layout:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
 var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
});
```

taken from this blog post: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/2/8/csrf-protection-bypass-in-ruby-on-rails.

In my case, the session was being reset upon each ajax request.  Adding the above code solved that issue.

Answer (score 10):

1. Make sure that you have `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` in your layout
2. Add a `beforeSend` to include the csrf-token in the ajax request to set the header. This is only required for `post` requests.

The code to read the csrf-token is available in the `rails/jquery-ujs`, so imho it is easiest to just use that, as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'post',
  beforeSend: $.rails.CSRFProtection,
  data: {
    // ...
  }
})
```

Comment: Simple without re-implementing what's already included by Rails.  This should be the selected answer.

Comment: In Rails 5.1 also works:
`headers: {
  'X-CSRF-Token': Rails.csrfToken()
}`

Comment: @nathanvda, Maybe you can answer this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159847/single-page-application-and-csrf-token

Answer (score 7):

The top voted answers here are correct but will not work if you are performing **cross-domain** requests because the session will not be available unless you explicitly tell jQuery to pass the session cookie. Here's how to do that:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
  },
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  }
});
```

Comment: May I ask you if you can answer this very similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159847/single-page-application-and-csrf-token

Answer (score 6):

I just thought I'd link this here as the article has most of the answer you're looking for and it's also very interesting

http://www.kalzumeus.com/2011/11/17/i-saw-an-extremely-subtle-bug-today-and-i-just-have-to-tell-someone/

Answer (score 6):

oops..

I missed the following line in my application.js

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

I replaced it and its working..

======= UPDATED =========

After 5 years, I am back with Same error, now I have brand new **Rails 5.1.6**, and I found this post again. Just like circle of life.

Now what was the issue is:
**Rails 5.1** removed support for *jquery* and *jquery_ujs* by default, and added

```
//= require rails-ujs in application.js
```

It does the following things:

1. force confirmation dialogs for various actions;
2. make non-GET requests from hyperlinks;
3. make forms or hyperlinks submit data asynchronously with Ajax;
4. have submit buttons become automatically disabled on form submit to prevent double-clicking.
   (from: https://github.com/rails/rails-ujs/tree/master)

But why is it not including the csrf token for ajax request? If anyone know about this in detail just comment me. I appreciate that.

Anyway I added the following in my custom js file to make it work (Thanks for other answers to help me reach this code):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': Rails.csrfToken()
    }
  });
  ----
  ----
});
```

Comment: This was what I needed to do as well. The reason this came up is because I'm building a React App to slowly replace an existing Rails App. Since there's a bunch of javascript noise going on in the existing app, I created a different layout that accesses a different javascript file, but I failed to include `jquery_ujs`. That was the trick.

Comment: Yes, Sometimes  If we miss that when rework, refactor something..Its hard to find whats going wrong. Because we are not doing anything manually to make it work, Rails automatically including it. We think it already there. Thanks for such social Qn / Ans Sites

Comment: Maybe you can answer this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159847/single-page-application-and-csrf-token

Answer (score 6):

You can write it globally like below.

Normal JS:

```
$(function(){

    $('#loader').hide()
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        $('#loader').show();
    })
    $(document).ajaxError(function() {
        alert("Something went wrong...")
        $('#loader').hide();
    })
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        $('#loader').hide();
    });
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))}
    });
});
```

Coffee Script:

```
  $('#loader').hide()
  $(document).ajaxStart ->
    $('#loader').show()

  $(document).ajaxError ->
    alert("Something went wrong...")
    $('#loader').hide()

  $(document).ajaxStop ->
    $('#loader').hide()

  $.ajaxSetup {
    beforeSend: (xhr) ->
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are not using jQuery and using something like [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) API for requests you can use the following to get the `csrf-token`:

`document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')`

```
fetch('/users', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')},
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    body: JSON.stringify( { id: 1, name: 'some user' } )
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log('request succeeded with JSON response', data)
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('request failed', error)
    })
```

Comment: May I ask you if you can answer this very similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159847/single-page-application-and-csrf-token

Answer (score 4):

Use jquery.csrf (https://github.com/swordray/jquery.csrf).

- Rails 5.1 or later

  ```sh
  $ yarn add jquery.csrf
  ```

  ```
  //= require jquery.csrf
  ```
- Rails 5.0 or before

  ```
  source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
    gem 'rails-assets-jquery.csrf'
  end
  ```

  ```
  //= require jquery.csrf
  ```
- Source code

  ```
  (function($) {
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
      var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
      if (token) xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);
    });
  })(jQuery);
  ```

Comment: In 5.1 using webpack, `//= require jquery.csrf` isn't going to work, right?. Instead I used pack js file with `import 'jquery.csrf'` in it. Note you do *not* need to include this with a pack tag in your views.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using javascript with jQuery to generate the token in your form, this works:

```
<input name="authenticity_token" 
       type="hidden" 
       value="<%= $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content') %>" />
```

Obviously, you need to have the `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` in your Ruby layout.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this issue for days. Any GET call was working correctly, but all PUTs would generate a "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" error. My website was working fine until I had added a SSL cert to nginx.

I finally stumbled on this missing line in my nginx settings:

```
location @puma { 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host; 
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;   # Needed to avoid 'WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity'
    proxy_pass http://puma; 
}
```

After adding the missing line "proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;", all my CSRF token errors quit.

Hopefully this helps someone else who also is beating their head against a wall. haha

Answer (score 1):

if someone needs help related with Uploadify and Rails 3.2 (like me when I googled this post), this sample app may be helpful: 
https://github.com/n0ne/Uploadify-Carrierwave-Rails-3.2.3/blob/master/app/views/pictures/index.html.erb

also check the controller solution in this app

Answer (score 1):

For those of you that do need a non jQuery answer you can simple add the following:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
```

A very simple example can be sen here:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","example.html",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Does this not use jQuery for selectors?

Comment: xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content);

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rails 4.2.4 and couldn't work out why I was getting:

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

I have in the layout:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

In the controller:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

Invoking `tcpdump -A -s 999 -i lo port 3000` was showing the header being set ( despite not needing to set the headers with `ajaxSetup` - it was done already):

```
X-CSRF-Token: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
DNT: 1
Content-Length: 125
authenticity_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

In the end it was failing because I had cookies switched off.  CSRF doesn't work without cookies being enabled, so this is another possible cause if you're seeing this error.

Comment: it's very helpfu!

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Rails 7 in 2023, I had this issue for some reason. Perhaps I'm using normal jQuery instead of some rails variant of jQuery, or whatever "UJS" is.

Fixed it by adding this to my page-specific Javascript code:

```
    // Add the CSRF token to all ajax requests                                                                                                                      
    $.ajaxSetup({                                                                                                                                                   
      headers: {                                                                                                                                                    
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')                                                                                                
      }                                                                                                                                                             
    });
```

(I already had `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` at the top of my html layout)

My normal jQuery Ajax code looks like:

```
      var jqxhr = $.post( "something/example", { color: 'red' })
        .done(function(data) {
          console.log( "Ajax success:");
          console.log( data );
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
          console.log( "Ajax error:");
          console.log( data );
        })
        .always(function() {
          console.log( "Ajax finished" );
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

CSRF token is missing while making API call. You can send ""X-CSRF-Token"" in the headers.
[name=""csrf-token""] is the html element where you can get the token.