# Sending forms to the rails application from outside HTML websites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, widget, form-submit

I need to submit forms from a couple of remote sites to the central rails application that processes and stores data. You can think about it as of widget form (something similar to what Wufoo service provides).

These outside sites are going to be pure HTML (what means no server-side scripting - only JS/jQuery at browser side). I am aware that straight way to get it would be to put the form inside of an iframe element but I'd be glad to avoid this.

What would be **a good and safe pattern** to build such interaction?

I wrote simply HTML form sending data to create action in proper controller and submit form with AJAX/jQuery. It almost works, however I got

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

warning so, I'm sure, this approach would not be useful in production.

May someone who is experienced provide me some advice? Thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941594/understand-rails-authenticity-token maybe this will be helpful

Comment: It seems that the solutions above work inside the Rails application. My forms are external HTML forms. I begin to think that an inframe is the only solution, especially I'm going to not use server scripting for external pages (pure HTML).