# Rails 3.2.6 session[:_csrf_token] different from meta tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, csrf, dalli

I have a Rails application that I've upgraded from 3.0.7 to 3.2.6. I use Dalli and memcached for my session store.

Since I've upgraded, I've started getting `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` errors, and my sessions are being reset.

I call `csrf_meta_tags` in my header.

In my ApplicationController, I've overridden `verify_authenticity_token` in order to check out what the app thinks the csrf_token is.

```
def verify_authenticity_token
  verified_request?
  Rails.logger.info "+++ VERIFY AUTH TOKEN +++"
  Rails.logger.info session.inspect
end
```

I submitted a form from my app, and the session data written to the logger was:
`{"_csrf_token"=>"4OQ47F2py+l12lLSTnq0RTmyPbmPi2UGMZaPhMG6vVQ="}`

This differs from the value set on the page in the meta tag and from the value submitted with the form:
`{"authenticity_token"=>"qMsdBkTHoBH09+X0tnyoPsbtc752yKjCVHddrcufd7g="}`

---

### PROBLEM SOLVED

It turns out this was due to a configuration error.

I had been setting the `session_store` config in config/initializers/session_store.rb:

```
require 'action_dispatch/middleware/session/dalli_store'
Rails.application.config.session_store :dalli_store
```

This was initialized for all environments, however in the development environment, the default config for caching is `config.perform_caching = false`.

Deleting the initializer file and moving the session store config to the production.rb file fixed the issue for me.

```
config.session_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211'
```

I'm just not sure why this wasn't an issue in 3.0.2, but is in 3.2.6.

Comment: have you seen that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails

Comment: @gabrielhilal, I had seen that, but thanks for the recommendation. My form isn't being submitted via AJAX though.

Comment: @whtt-eric, glad you figured it out! But rather than writing your solution into the question, you should take the bit after "PROBLEM SOLVED" and post it as an answer to your question. Then, when you're allowed to, you can accept your own answer. This lets everyone know that this answer has been solved, without having to read to the end of your question.