# Rails 3 : Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When i tried to post data through my REST Client ,i am getting a warning like this

```
Warning :Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
```

How to solve this.

Comment: That a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are trying to make a `POST` from a `link`. By default `links` aren't supposed to make `POST` requests, only `GET` ones. So when you try to make the connection to your server, `Rails` warns you about this.
One way to bypass this kind of behavior is, instead of using a `link`, use a `form`. So you can make proper `POST` requests to the server.
Alternatively, you can remove the `protect_from_forgery` line from your `application_controller`, so `Rails` doesn't do this kind of verification, but this is extremely not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this, (but not recommended :)), skip forgery protection

Ex: you are posting data to PostController => Create action

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

   before_filter :protect_from_forgery, :except => [:create]  

   def create
        #your method
   end
end
```

but having said that, I'm sure there should be a better way to do what you want to do, so if you could explain what you want to do, someone could help

HTH

Comment: I upvoted this because I wanted to know how to handle this warning, not because I wanted to skip it. Don't skip forgery protection!

Answer (score 1):

nop

I missed the following line in my application.js

```
//= require jquery_ujs
```

I replaced it and its working..