# CSRF token authencity for sub controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, controller, csrf-protection

I am getting CSRF warning (resetting my session) in my rails apps whenever I post to my api_controller.rb.

My app is run on iframe in phonegap for windows phone 8 and in my application_controller, I have a p3p header to solve just this problem.  But it doesn't seem to work in this case.  Its like the p3p is not there...?  Has anyone encountered this?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

protect_from_forgery
before_filter :header_fix

protected
  def header_fix
    headers['P3P'] = 'CP="ALL DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND COM NAV"'
  end
end




class Api::ApiController < ApplicationController
before_filter :login_required

skip_before_filter :detect_device
skip_before_filter :detect_browser
skip_before_filter :record_log

skip_before_filter :assign_packages
skip_before_filter :assign_daily_bonus

end


[2646 - 2013/04/05 13:04:23] (INFO) Started POST "/api/chests" for 60.50.19.249 at 2013-04-05 13:04:23 +0800
[2646 - 2013/04/05 13:04:23] (INFO) Processing by Api::ChestsController#create as */*
[2646 - 2013/04/05 13:04:23] (INFO)   Parameters: {"force_new"=>"true"}
[2646 - 2013/04/05 13:04:23] (WARN) WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
[2646 - 2013/04/05 13:04:23] (INFO) User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920)
[2646 - 2013/04/05 13:04:23] (DEBUG)   User Load (4.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
[2646 - 2013/04/05 13:04:23] (DEBUG)   KeyPackage Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `packages`.* FROM `packages` WHERE `packages`.`type` IN ('KeyPackage') ORDER BY cost
[2646 - 2013/04/05 13:04:23] (DEBUG)   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
[2646 - 2013/04/05 13:04:23] (DEBUG)   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
[2646 - 2013/04/05 13:04:23] (WARN) Lost session [60.50.19.249] (/api/chests) - Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920)
```

Comment: is the user logged in prior to the request?

Comment: yes the users is login, rails console shows the user id for all events prior to posting

Comment: does it work, when you access the contents of the iframe directly (without the iframe with a browser)?

Comment: yes, it works when i do that

Comment: maybe this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails

Comment: already been through all of that.. there is no problem with the p3p header

Answer (score 1):

This gem works for Ruby on Rails (https://github.com/grosser/ie_iframe_cookies).  Solves the problem.

Even though my p3p header is valid and my user can login, I am not sure why IE10 does this.