# rails 401 error even after i set X-CSRF-Token header successfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-validate, csrf

I am making a signup form and wanted to use jquery-validation plugin to check that user_name is unique.

The routes:

```
resources :users, :only => [:show] do
  collection do                      
    post 'check_user_name_uniq'     
    get 'check_email'                
    get 'check_password'             
  end
```

controller:

```
def check_user_name_uniq
  render :json => User.valid_attribute?(:user_name, params[:user][:user_name]).to_json
end
```

javascript:

```
$("#new_user").validate({
  debug: true,
  rules: {
    "user[user_name]": {
      required: true,           
      remote: {
        url:  "/users/check_user_name_uniq", // check user_name uniqueness
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json"
      }
    }                                        
  },...
```

And i set the X-CSRF-Token header by:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
  }
});
```

But when i enter a user_name, there was still 401 error:

```
Started POST "/users/check_user_name_uniq" for 192.168.157.1 at 2013-04-26 23:52:22 +0800
Processing by UsersController#check_user_name_uniq as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"user_name"=>"tomwang"}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 36ms
```

I don't know why this error happened, because they said that the header could solve it:
[WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` is present in your layout?