# Rails 3 Authenticity tokens: How to prevent it from using spaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3 and javascript to make POST requests and therefore I need an authenticity token. However, the token Rails creates keeps including spaces, and I can't have that in my javascript URL string. Here's how it looks like in my log right now:

```
Started POST "/cart/update?authenticity_token=fjJJQc2gKBenzzAAqdvhprJxH2tnhYkyuZ9F+l+GFns=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-23 11:55:42 -0400
Processing by CartController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"gift_card_amount"=>"undefined", "case_quantity"=>"", "bottle_quantity"=>"", "product_history_id"=>"1052981", "authenticity_token"=>"fjJJQc2gKBenzzAAqdvhprJxH2tnhYkyuZ9F l GFns="}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

This is my HTML:

```
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" class="button-yellow">Add to Cart</a>
    <%= hidden_field_tag form_authenticity_token %>
    <script>
        window._token = '<%= form_authenticity_token %>';
    </script>
```

And my javascript:

```
$.post('/cart/update?authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent(window._token), ...
```

Notice I tried using `encodeURIComponent`, but that doesn't seem to work. However, the problem still persists and I feel like it's Rails and not javascript. How would I change the Rails token to not include spaces? gsub  for `+` like it does in javascript?

Comment: The authenticity token is base64 encoded.  `+` signs are valid in base64 encoding and do not represent spaces.  `+` signs in URLs *do* represent spaces.  So URL-encoding the token would be necessary if you need to send it as a URL parameter.  To avoid this problem you could send the token as a POST parameter.  However @0x0uLL's answer looks like the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should actually send the csrf token in the header instead of sending it as a parameter. Also make sure you have `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` in your layout. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175979/2081133).