# How can I include the authenticity_token without using form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have many small pages that do not correspond to standard resource-based forms in my Rails 3.2.13 project. I am using Ajax calls from these forms to do POSTs. I'm getting the error:

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

which is causing my session to be invalidated and I'm redirected to the login page.

How can I include the CSRF stuff without using `form_for`?

Comment: It may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails ; you can also get the CRSF value with `form_authenticity_token`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include the hidden input field with CSRF token in your view, use

```
<%= hidden_field_tag(request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, form_authenticity_token) %>
```

`form_for` uses the method [`FormTagHelper.token_tag`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4179470f0116a08a1838c474ba5541bb33658c9d/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L670-677), but it's a private method and can't be used directly.