# Rails: CSRF token not working but setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have my rails 3 app on heroku and when I send bank info I get: `WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` but my CSRF token is set up. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7081401

```
$.ajax({ url: '#{credit_cards_path}', 
type: 'POST',
beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', '#{form_authenticity_token}')},
dataType: "json",
data: { cc_uri: response.data.uri, 
        address: $('.address').val()
        // etc ...
      },
success: function(randomobject) {
  window.location = '/products/' + randomobject.value + '/receipt';
  }
});
```

heroku logs

```
829962+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/products/2/card" for 100.2.109.97 at 2013-10-21 09:13:03 +0000
835379+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
834929+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CreditcardsController#addcard as HTML
834929+00:00 app[web.1]: Parameters: {"state"=>"NY", "id"=>"2"}
604099+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/products/2/card host=app.herokuapp.com fwd="100.2.109.97" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1781ms status=500 bytes=643
604259+00:00 app[web.1]:
602739+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1768ms
604259+00:00 app[web.1]: Balanced::BadRequest (Balanced::BadRequest(400)::Bad Request:: POST https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/customers: request: Invalid field [card_uri] - "None" must be a string URI Your request id is OHMfe86f2883a3011e3980d02a1fe53e539. ):
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the value of `#{form_authenticity_token}` is being outputted correctly in the compiled javascript?

Comment: is that a compiled javascript? like an js.erb file? are you regenerating it for each request?

Comment: yes phoet this gets generated when i get a successfull callback from my payment api each time

Answer (score 4):

Might be to do with your use of `#{form_authenticity_token}`

According to this source [WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails) you should be able to use this code:

```
headers: {
  'X-Transaction': 'POST Example',
  'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
},
```

Comment: It's getting there, but there is another issue I can see. You're trying to include ruby variables in a .js file. Before trying my solution, try changing your `balanced.js` to `balanced.js.erb` and see what happens with your original code

Comment: ahh solved it!! turns out my javascript wasn't actually getting to the browser i seemed to forgot to put in //=require myjs.js

Comment: lol! I always find people ask questions on SO, but their problem is actually not related to the thing they have the problem with! If you have any further requirements, please let me know!