# Internal Server Error while submitting devise login form on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting internal server 500 while submitting devise login form. In heroku logs, it says that `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` , but I do have CSRF token in login form and this is completely working on my localhost.

Heroku logs

```
2014-02-18T22:12:55.779665+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 0.0.0.0 at 2014-02-18 22:12:55 +0000
2014-02-18T22:12:55.779665+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 0.0.0.0 at 2014-02-18 22:12:55 +0000
2014-02-18T22:12:55.785405+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-02-18T22:12:55.785405+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
2014-02-18T22:12:55.785405+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rEKLcjNF7KlhQOfOCMW5azPIpFZWFsLWRfgsFQVcmcs=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
2014-02-18T22:12:55.785405+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rEKLcjNF7KlhQOfOCMW5azPIpFZWFsLWRfgsFQVcmcs=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
2014-02-18T22:12:55.786314+00:00 app[web.1]: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
2014-02-18T22:12:55.786314+00:00 app[web.1]: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
2014-02-18T22:12:55.789168+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 4ms
2014-02-18T22:12:55.789243+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 4ms
2014-02-18T22:12:55.790658+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-02-18T22:12:55.790658+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
2014-02-18T22:12:55.790781+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rEKLcjNF7KlhQOfOCMW5azPIpFZWFsLWRfgsFQVcmcs=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
2014-02-18T22:12:55.790833+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rEKLcjNF7KlhQOfOCMW5azPIpFZWFsLWRfgsFQVcmcs=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
2014-02-18T22:12:55.791437+00:00 app[web.1]: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
2014-02-18T22:12:55.791437+00:00 app[web.1]: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
2014-02-18T22:12:55.791897+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2014-02-18T22:12:55.791897+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794553+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794553+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `destroy_session' for nil:NilClass):
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794553+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:85:in `destroy'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794553+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:257:in `reset_session'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794553+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/rails/warden_compat.rb:8:in `reset_session!'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794553+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/proxy.rb:268:in `logout'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794553+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:168:in `sign_out_all_scopes'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794553+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:275:in `handle_unverified_request'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794553+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:177:in `verify_authenticity_token'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794553+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:417:in `_run__3351252874345740854__process_action__callbacks'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794731+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794731+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794731+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794731+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794731+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794731+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794731+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794731+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794731+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794731+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:51:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:51:in `recall'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:35:in `respond'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.794895+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795426+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799047+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/users/sign_in host=advertype-akhil.herokuapp.com request_id=a4583a05-850d-43f8-bba4-a7f9e4065005 fwd="49.249.135.78" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=24ms status=500 bytes=722
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795426+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795426+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795426+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:20:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795426+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:20:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795426+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/delegator.rb:5:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795426+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:130:in `call_failure_app'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795426+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:116:in `process_unauthenticated'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795426+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:47:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795426+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.795656+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796115+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2905009366359532870__call__callbacks'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796115+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796115+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796115+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796115+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796115+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796115+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796115+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796115+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796115+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796407+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796407+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796407+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796407+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796407+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796407+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796407+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796407+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796407+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796407+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/deflater.rb:25:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796851+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796851+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-18T22:12:55.796851+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797107+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797107+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `destroy_session' for nil:NilClass):
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797107+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:85:in `destroy'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797107+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:257:in `reset_session'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797107+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/rails/warden_compat.rb:8:in `reset_session!'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797107+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/proxy.rb:268:in `logout'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797107+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:168:in `sign_out_all_scopes'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797107+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:275:in `handle_unverified_request'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797107+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:177:in `verify_authenticity_token'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797107+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:417:in `_run__3351252874345740854__process_action__callbacks'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797713+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797713+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797713+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797713+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797713+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797713+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797713+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797713+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797713+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797713+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797967+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797967+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797967+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797967+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797967+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797967+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:51:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797967+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:51:in `recall'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797967+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:35:in `respond'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797967+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.797967+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:20:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:20:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.0.0/lib/devise/delegator.rb:5:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:130:in `call_failure_app'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:116:in `process_unauthenticated'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:47:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798611+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798959+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798959+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798959+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798959+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798959+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798959+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798959+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798959+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798959+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.798959+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2905009366359532870__call__callbacks'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799587+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799819+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799819+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799819+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799819+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799819+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799819+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799819+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799819+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799819+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.799819+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.800374+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.800374+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/deflater.rb:25:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.800374+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.800374+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.800374+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.800374+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.800374+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-02-18T22:12:55.800374+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Any help and suggestions are really appreciable, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment as I don't have enough votes but here is the answer from earlier SO post that had same issue like your's on Heroku platform:

[Rails: CSRF token not working but setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503632/rails-csrf-token-not-working-but-setup)

Hope this helps.