# How to set default values for future Http Requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dart, csrf

Is it possible to set default values for future [Http Requests](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_html/HttpRequest.html) such as in [jQuery.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) ?

The reason behind this question is the need to [send CSRF tokens for every request in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175979/1779281).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a functionality.
I would create a method that prepares the HTTPRequest and returns it initialized with the preferred defaults?