# `InvalidAuthenticityToken` error in rails post route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, csrf-protection

I have a rails app with a POST url which creates some resources.I have a page with a form which takes in all the information and does an AJAX call to the POST url without authenticity token.

Am doing `data["authenticity_token"] = "";`, before doing the AJAX call.

Parameters logged on serverside are like below

`{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"", "company_customer"=>{"name"=>"Anand"}}`

The resources are created without any error(I have `protect_from_forgery with: :exception` in my `ApplicationController`).

But when I tried to call the same POST url from Postman, I get `InvalidAuthenticityToken` error.

1. Why am I getting the error?
2. How does the rails app verify the authenticity of the POST request in first case?

Answer (score 0):

In the first step i.e. from browser , you might be having some session id in the cookies but here not.

Also, if you were hitting by `remote:true` option, it will take the authenticity token from the page in the hidden field.

For more details , check your logs in both cases.

Comment: am not doing `remote: true`. Am serializing the input fields and sending it using jQuery ajax call. While sending tge request, am making the `authenticity_token` as nil(for testing). Still the request is processed without any error. But when I send the request from postman without authenticity_token I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

This token is automatically added in as hidden field when you are using `form_for` helper method to generate forms, so Rails makes sure the request comes from one of your forms.

You should unprotect your controller action when requested from postman or any other app, see how to here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22715175/8352929

Comment: Fyi, the referenced solution introduces a csrf vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

You can find how CSRF works from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1571900/2422068). I recommend you go through it.

Whenever you use `form_for` Rails adds one hidden input field to your form which looks like the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="doLYVxrkhdrzn7zzriHXjFE6ZhNCuXVxLrau4ouENmuKKC/SWp2NMM/MeL/Ji2tDvzNcJHVN/Hc0LIluL3o5QQ==" />
```

Also, Rails include CSRF token in the meta tags of the website which looks like the following:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="zxnmBxg81JUQPG/C/wb3HRCah0m9Xe2A+gZ5N0Oy7cfwC+dF4hC325WxdVDLfkIxcw/CR/xyaC1phpvZ4EcgQw==" />
```

So, when you use Rails `form_for` or something similar to make AJAX call(may be with `remote: true`) the authenticity token is sent to the server. Which was not present when you tried to send the same request with Postman.

If you copy the CSRF token and add it to Postman params, the request will be completed successfully.

Comment: I have commented for one of the answer above, still I will paste that here again.                 I am not doing `remote: true`. Am serializing the input fields and sending it using jQuery ajax call. While sending tge request, am making the `authenticity_token` as nil(for testing). Still the request is processed without any error. But when I send the request from postman without authenticity_token I get the error.

Comment: Can you confirm the same by checking `params` under server logs? And also please update your question with the information

Comment: `jquery-ujs` automatically adds CSRF token while using POST with jquery. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162218/jquerys-ajax-function-automatically-adds-csrf-token

Comment: I am manually making the `authenticity_token` nil before making AJAX request. I checked in the server log, token is coming as blank. That's why I got confused. How come the request is authenticated without the `authenticity_token`? In that case it should have worked with postman also

Comment: Can you dump the server logs and jQuery code responsible for the AJAX call in the question?