# Rails post can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, csrf

I've check this [WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails)
but I still can't figure it out why it cause this error.

Here is my `ajax`

```
 $.post(
      "<%= ajax_chats_path %>",
      {timestamp :(new Date()).getTime(),msg: $('#msg').val()},
      function (json) {
      console.log(json);
    });
```

If I add this

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

in controller, it can solve this problem.

I am not sure it's the right way to do, because it looks like it may encounter some security attack.

Comment: please see here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails

Comment: I've checked it, but I still don't know how to modify into my ajax. I am new in developing javascript and rails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the CSRF token in your Ajax call.  You'll need to use a long-form $.ajax call, and add this:

```
beforeSend: $.rails.CSRFProtection
```

Instead of `$.post`, you can use the `$.ajax` equivalent, which would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<%= ajax_chats_path %>",
    beforeSend: $.rails.CSRFProtection,
    data: {
        timestamp: (new Date()).getTime(),
        msg: $('#msg').val(),
        beforeSend: $.rails.CSRFProtection
    },
    success: function (json) {
      console.log(json);
    }
});
```

You should also strongly consider adding the `datatype` field to the call, so that jQuery knows the disposition of the response and can handle it accordingly.  You can choose from any of "xml", "json", "html", "script", "jsonp", or "text".  See the [jQuery.ajax() API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help. I will add `datatype` later!

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me,

```
$.ajax({
  beforeSend(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
  },
```