# Can I pass data in an AJAX call without the data key?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I'm doing an ajax call to a Rails 4.2 app setup with devise like this:

```
    $.ajax
      url: '/some_ajax_call',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend: (xhr) ->
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
      data: { yo: "yes" },
      success: (response) ->
        console.log('hello')
```

I end up with a params hash in the Rails controller structured like this:

```
{ "data" => { "yo" => "yes" } }  #params
```

Is there a way to do the AJAX call so that I end up with the following params hash instead (basically the params minus the data key)

```
{ "yo" => "yes" }  #params
```

Comment: You shouldn't encode the header for the CSRF yourself. Use the Rails helper to do it. Adding beforeSend: $.rails.CSRFProtection fixes the CSRF problem. See this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337691/rails-post-cant-verify-csrf-token-a‌​uthenticity/37337966#37337966](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337691/rails-post-cant-verify-csrf-token-a‌​uthenticity/37337966#37337966)

Comment: @MichaelGaskill where does the `$.rails.CSRFProtection` come from?  It's not part of jQuery, right?

Comment: It's an unobtrusive javascript (UJS) helper provided by Rails.  You can find it in `rails.js` if you're looking for it in the Rails source.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass params in the url:

```
 url: '/some_ajax_call?yo=yes'
```