# What is the difference between request.cookies and cookies in a controller?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a difference between `request.cookies` and `cookies` object in Ruby on Rails?

I am currently trying to send a request with a cookie from my node.js server to my ROR4 application. It seems that in the ROR application, `request.cookies` contains the cookie that I am sending however `cookies` object (on which existing logic is based) do not have it.

I have searched the docs but was not able to find anything relevant. Is there something that I have missed? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I faced the same problem. Did you figure out the reason behind the difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ideally, `request.cookies` and `cookies` should be the same. However, in POST (create action) requests, rails verifies the XSRF token. If that verification fails, the cookies from `request.cookies` are not available in the `request.cookie_jar`. Which means, they are not available via the `cookies` method.

To identify if the cookies mismatch is because of the XSRF token missing. In your request, try to identify the class of your cookie hash. `cookies.hash` should return you `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar`. If it instead returns `ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection::ProtectionMethods::NullSession::NullCookieJar`, you have a XSRF token mismatch.

This scenario is likely to happen when you make these calls via javascript which don't by default pick the XSRF token and send with the request. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175979/976880 to learn how to fix it.

Comment: FYI: Instaed of `cookies.hash`, you can also do `cookies.class`

Answer (score 6):

`request.cookies` is a [Rack provided](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1-6-stable/lib/rack/request.rb#L295) method. It is just a hash of key value pairs, obtained by parsing the cookie header.

The controller `cookies` method returns `request.cookie_jar`. The cookie jar is built from the exact same `request.cookies` data, but parses it adds a bunch of rails functionality on top, such as signed cookies, serialising data into cookies etc.

I can't see any reason why a key would be present in one, but not the other.