# Trouble showing https modal from http page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, https, modal-dialog

I have a Rails 3.2.21 app, which requires the user to be logged in to do several actions (e.g. following another user).

The issue is I've switched *ONLY* the login & signup pages to **https**; the rest of the app is still http (using [rack-ssl-enforcer](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer) gem to 301 redirect from http -> https on just those two pages, in case it matters). When opening up a modal via Ajax to show login or signup, it's not working. In the Rails logs it says:

`WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

And in Chrome the console says:

`Failed to load https://mydomain/signup: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydomain' is therefore not allowed access.`

The code looks like this. Clicking the link to follow a user runs the following jQuery code:

`$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/follow/" + $(this).data("follow-id")
})`

The `FollowsController` has `before_filter :login_required`, and  the `login_required` method in `ApplicationController` looks like this:

`def login_required
  redirect_to "/signup" and return
end`

Without the login & signup pages being https, everything works as normal. When I switched them to https, this problem crept up.

**EDIT:**

Already tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175979/1231503), to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rack-cors gem](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to the rescue. That did the trick.