# How to make authenticated ajax requests with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5 (not API) and Devise for authentication.

I have a custom action that needs to be triggered by ajax. For unauthenticated requests it works, but this particular request needs to be authenticated.

How do I do it?

Comment: I guess you need to add csrf token to headers.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203304/warning-cant-verify-csrf-token-authenticity-rails

Comment: @MaksimP that works, thanks!